# How can I extract the numerical value from the result of FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, core-language

[image: code]

I've to use previous values of FindRoot to implement my program (recursively), but the type of  the output from `FindRoot` is not a number. How can I extract the numerical value?

Comment: An answer is given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/4999), and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html), and an alternative is given in the docs for [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html).

Comment: `FindRoot[...][[1,2]]`?